# How to move to the "Nth" offset in a file

Tags: text-processing, vi

I'm in need of a command that would get the *N* th offset in a file.
Say this is my file's contents:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /file1.txt
this is the the first line of many lines
and is just a sample file
```

I'd like to find the character at the 6th offset using a command which in this case is `i`.

Is there any command or `vi` editor command that would work?

Answer (score 3):

```
dd bs=1 skip=5 count=1 <infile
```

---

```
i
```

...or, if you like to share...

```
{ dd bs=5 skip=1 count=0; cat; } <infile
```

---

```
is the the first line of many lines
and is just a sample file
```

...though that *offset* is by *byte* not *char*. Still, with a regular input file, `dd` isn't easily matched for seeking to offsets.

Comment: Does this not print all the records in records out rubbish as well ?

Comment: @123 - i don't follow. `<` opens a stream. `dd` seeks that stream `skip=` count `i*bs=` blocks in. In the second example `cat` picks up the stream where `dd` leaves it - as any other utility might. `dd` *might* print whatever rubbish you like, I suppose.

Comment: it prints stuff like `0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 1.0119e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s
` as well as the actual data you want.

Comment: @123 - that's on stderr. do `2>/dev/null` if you're not interested.

Comment: Okay :), might have been useful to add it to the answe though as i assume OP does not want that information.

Comment: @123 - why would you assume that? and again - that's a separate output stream.

Comment: `why would you assume that`, because they don't ask for it nor is there any indication that they want it. They say they want to find the 6th character, not the number of records dd has processed.

Comment: @123 - thats a separate output stream. it is nothing but statistical log data. you only see it at all because youre running it live at a terminal where both stderr and stdout go by default. anyone scripting such a thing in order to capture only a particular portion of input and - as i assume - filtering it to some other process for some reason should either be handling stderr anyway, or should receive that information until know enough to discard it. its reported specifically to help you hone such code to do what you mean to do. either way, it is generally not relevant to IPC.

Comment: I pretty much agree, but your answer makes it appear that the only output from the command is STDOUT. Also i don't know what IPC means ?

Comment: @123 - thats ok. you made me laugh just now anyway. IPC is interprocess communication. `{ echo ill communicate with the process on the other end of this pipefile with my IPC pipefile connected to my stdout; echo >&2 and ill write some rubbish to stderr for the human trying to figure out how best to arrange my affairs while you do; } | : and all of the first echos output will be directed at this null command and so go nowhere, but the second echos stderr never comes here`

Comment: `made me laugh just now`, because i didn't know what `IPC` meant? Also i understand that STDERR doesn't get through the pipe unless specified. But it will be printed to screen unless you specifically tell it not to. I.e in the middle of your program in the middle of data you want to see. Again im assuming, but im guessing OP would eventually want something printed to screen.

Comment: @123 - yes. it made me laugh - not that you didnt know what IPC was, but that you didnt know but still agreed. i thought it was a little funny, i dont mean that to be rude. i dont know what the OP wants. if the question was about redirecting stderr I would have thought more about it, maybe. but it wasn't - it was about skipping input to output. and so thats what i thought about. i didnt include the stderr in the literally pasted output examples because it was not written to my clipboard when i piped the output to it. because it is a separate stream.  if you feel this needs an edit - edit it.

Comment: Thats why i said pretty much, couldn't completely agree if i didn't know what IPC stood for! I was just suggesting it might be helpful, if you don't think it is or it's not relevant then it's your answer, still a good answer either way :)

Answer (score 3):

In `vim`, `:goto 6` or, `6go` will move the cursor to the graphem that contains the 6th byte in the current buffer.

If the offset points to a newline character, it will position the cursor at the end of the corresponding line (on you sample, `40go` and `41go` will bring the cursor to the same position).

Answer (score 1):

`Cut` is what you are looking for.

```
cut -b6 file1.txt
```

This shows you the 6th byte...per line of the file. I think you only want the 6th byte so you can use something like `head`

```
head -n1 file1.txt | cut -b6
```

Voila.

Comment: Strictly speaking this shows the 6th *byte* of the file.  If you want the 6th *character* and the file may be in Unicode (or other multi-byte per character format), use `cut -6c file1.txt` instead.  As for "all possible variations of the command", you should see `man cut` as well as [the POSIX specifications for the `cut` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html).

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for the 6th byte to the very of the file. I don't want the 6th byte on wards in every single line. It should be the absolute 6th byte in that file :)  Any command to help me with this. I don't think "cut" can achieve this based on what I've read up on "cut"

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar as Wildcard points out, it is technically the 6th byte that cut -b gives you. Try it.

Comment: Won't this fail if the first line has less than 6 bytes ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar Did you actually read the 2nd paragraph, or...?

Answer (score 1):

Another way using od --

```
 od -An -c -j 5 -N1 file
 i
```

Comment: that depends heavily on the `od`.